# I would like to batch change one colour in a group of PNGs. Mac - freeware software

Tags: batch, colors, png

I hope someone would be able to help me.

I have a group of icons in png format. They are all transparent backgrounds with one colour for the actual icon. I would like to change this colour in all of the pngs to a different colour.

Could someone suggest a good way to accomplish this?

I have only freeware software and a mac.

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: When I looked for "batch image editor mac", I found lots of tools. Which have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

GNU offer  `gimp` (GNU Image Manipulation Program) - it's free and has most of the features other image editing tools such as photoshop have.
I've used it for photo editing on Mac and Linux and found it very useful.

http://www.gimp.org/downloads/